# Replace a string from a particular line in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file which has a lot of information. The file may gets updated with time. My question is i have a text which is in a particular line ( line number is not fixed). The only identifier is starting of the line:
Eg:

`A=I love you Mary.`
`B=I love you Suzi.`
`C=I love you Jimmy`
`D=I love you Mary and Jimmy.`

Now here i want to change Mary with Maria only where the unique identifier is "A". I cannot do it with line number as A can be in any line. I dont want to change last line which also have the word Mary.

Comment: I think the formatting is confusing; they *appear* to all be on one line, but I get the feeling those are supposed to be four separate lines?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do it would be to ask `sed` to make the change only on lines that match the pattern. For example, so change the first "Mary" to "Maria" on lines that start with "A=":

```
sed '/^A=/s/Mary/Maria/' < input > output
```

To change *all* of the "Mary" text to "Maria" on lines that start with "A=":

```
sed '/^A=/s/Mary/Maria/g' < input > output
```

Some sed implementations support a `-i` flag to do "in-place" editing; what it really does is make the changes to a temporary file and then copy that temporary file over the original. With those sed implementations, you could make the change in-place with:

```
sed -i '/^A=/s/Mary/Maria/' input
```